# Java not accepting File as Input

Tags: java, arrays, input, file-io

I am trying to read in a file of integers that will be sorted and then output into a different file. It can do everything except take the input file in terminal. I am not sure why, I have included the entire code and the commented portion is the part that doesn't seem to work (since when I hard code an array into the code it works fine). Thanks in advance.

```
class Quicksort {
    public void qSort(int[] a, int p, int r) {
        if (p < r) {
            int q = Partition(a, p, r);
            qSort(a, p, q - 1);
            qSort(a, q + 1, r);
        }
    }

    private static int Partition(int[] A, int p, int r) {
        int x = A[p];
        System.out.println(x + " ");
        int i = p;
        int j = r;
        int temp = 0;

        while (true) {
            while (A[j] > x) {
                j--;
            }

            while (A[i] < x) {
                i++;
            }

            if (i < j) {
                temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[i];
                A[i] = temp;
            } else {
                return j;
            }
        }

    }
}

public class QuickSortTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long time1 = System.nanoTime();
        Quicksort qsort = new Quicksort();

        //          ArrayList<Integer> dataReadIn = new ArrayList();
        //          FileReader fileToBeRead = new FileReader("test.txt");
        //          Scanner src = new Scanner(fileToBeRead);
        //          src.useDelimiter("[,\\s*]");
        //          int p = 0;
        //               while (src.hasNext()) 
        //               {
        //                   if (src.hasNext()) 
        //                   {
        //                       dataReadIn.add(src.nextInt());
        //                       System.out.println(p);
        //                       p++;
        //                     } 
        //                     else {
        //                         break;
        //                     }
        //                 }
        //           
        //      int[] array = new int[dataReadIn.size()];
        //     for(int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
        //     {
        //     array[a] = dataReadIn.get(a);
        //     }

        int[] array = { 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78,
                79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 26, 28 };
        int length = array.length;
        System.out.println(length);
        System.out.println("Pivot Element: ");
        qsort.qSort(array, 0, length - 1);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("OutputArray"));
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }

        out.close();
        long time2 = System.nanoTime();
        long time = (time2 - time1) / 1000;
        System.out.println("Total time: " + time + "ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? FileNotFoundException? If so, is the file in the same directory as the java file?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `doesn't seem to work`? It doesn't compile? Fails with exception? Gives unexpected results?

Comment: I suggest that you remove `Quicksort` class from code example. It seems to be irrelevant to this question.

Comment: The actual error would be useful. Is it `FileNotFoundException` or maybe a `NullPointerException` at a certain point?

Comment: It compiles just fine, and the file is in the same directory as the java file, and it allows you to see that there is a file there but it seems to think the file is empty.

Comment: I know this doesn't solve the problem, but your if-else code in the `while` is useless. `while` already checks the condition, and when it's not fulfilled anymore, it will stop, no need for `break`

Comment: Did you try debugging it and see when does it stop at runtime? Would be helpful to know if it crashes when it tries to open the file or at another point

Comment: It never reads the file so therefore it never has anything to sort or print and runs to the final point and quits.

Comment: Have you tried having the program just print out the text of the file to see whether it does that correctly?

Comment: Okay, that's weird. The code seems to be OK. Are you sure the file name and location correspond? I can't find anything wrong with the code

Comment: Yes I tried that by implementing an int called p above the while loop and setting it equal to 0, then trying to add it to the input on each pass and printing that out. It proceeded to print out nothing so it never saw anything to activate the while loop.

Comment: Try removing the QuickSort for now, and try printing `p` before you search for the next int in the file. If doesn't work, either your file is empty (!?) or there is something wrong with your code and none of us car figure it out

Comment: Just curious...what is this line trying to do? `src.useDelimiter("[,\\s*]");`

Comment: `src.useDelimiter("[,\\s*]");` should ignore those characters and sometimes is used to split strings in words or substrings based on some rule

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is your file is not found by the code.

There are 2 solutions for your problem :

1. Pass in the absolute path to the file when instantiating FileReader
2. Make sure the file is in the classpath and use getClass().getResourceAsStream and pass that to instantiate the Scanner (you won't need the FileReader class)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure **`*` doesn't work inside `[]`** in a regex (by "doesn't work" I mean it's treated as the actual character, not 1-or-more) (assuming you meant 1-or-more white-space characters). You can put `*` outside: (matches one or more white-space characters or commas)

```
src.useDelimiter("[,\\s]+");
```

or do something like this: (match either a comma or one or more white-space characters)

```
src.useDelimiter("(,|\\s+)");
```

I'm not entirely sure either of the above will actually work, it may be simpler just to use: (one or more non-digit characters)

```
src.useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
```

Note I changed the `*` to a `+`, otherwise the scanner will match on length 0 strings and may return digit by digit rather than a whole number.

**Also, your while-loop is somewhat overcomplicated. This would be simpler:**

```
int p = 0;
while (src.hasNext()) 
{
  dataReadIn.add(src.nextInt());
  System.out.println(p++);
}
```